# LoadError: cannot load such file -- config/deploy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano3

Ubuntu 20.04, Ruby 3.0.1, rails 6.1.3.1, Capistrano Version: 3.16.0 (Rake Version: 13.0.3)

Running any "cap" command results in the follow, for example :-

```
>> bundle exec cap install --trace
(in /)
cap aborted!
LoadError: cannot load such file -- config/deploy
Did you mean?  rbconfig/sizeof
/Capfile:4:in `load'
/Capfile:4:in `<top (required)>'
/home/mike/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:29:in `load'
/home/mike/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:29:in `load_rakefile'
/home/mike/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:703:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/home/mike/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:104:in `block in load_rakefile'
/home/mike/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/mike/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:103:in `load_rakefile'
/home/mike/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:82:in `block in run'
/home/mike/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/mike/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:80:in `run'
/home/mike/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/capistrano-3.16.0/lib/capistrano/application.rb:14:in `run'
/home/mike/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/capistrano-3.16.0/bin/cap:3:in `<top (required)>'
/home/mike/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/bin/cap:23:in `load'
/home/mike/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/bin/cap:23:in `<top (required)>'
/home/mike/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.16/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:63:in `load'
/home/mike/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.16/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:63:in `kernel_load'
/home/mike/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.16/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:28:in `run'
/home/mike/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.16/lib/bundler/cli.rb:494:in `exec'
/home/mike/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.16/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
/home/mike/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.16/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
/home/mike/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.16/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
/home/mike/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.16/lib/bundler/cli.rb:30:in `dispatch'
/home/mike/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.16/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:485:in `start'
/home/mike/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.16/lib/bundler/cli.rb:24:in `start'
/home/mike/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.16/exe/bundle:49:in `block in <top (required)>'
/home/mike/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.16/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:130:in `with_friendly_errors'
/home/mike/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.16/exe/bundle:37:in `<top (required)>'
/home/mike/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
/home/mike/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
```

I've tried creating new rails apps and the same error occurs.

Tried many different approaches (down grading ruby, rails etc) with same outcome. I think it may be a permissions issue and any help gratefully received.

**UPDATE #2**

Yep, running the command in the root of the application.

See code snippets below.

```
~/WebProjects/test_site$ ls -1
app
bin
config
config.ru
db
Gemfile
Gemfile.lock
lib
log
package.json
public
Rakefile
README.md
storage
test
tmp
vendor

~/WebProjects/test_site$ bundle exec cap install

(produces the error output in the question above)
```

Feels like something really simple but I just can't fathom it out (after many hours of head scratching!).

**UPDATE #3**

```
~/WebProjects/test_site$ cat /Capfile
load 'deploy' if respond_to?(:namespace) # cap2 differentiator
Dir['vendor/plugins/*/recipes/*.rb'].each { |plugin| load(plugin) }

load 'config/deploy' # remove this line to skip loading any of the default tasks
```

Comment: Are you sure the you have not run that command before? It looks like the `Capfile` was already generated.

Comment: I have run the command before on the machine but not for this project. 

For example, I've just set up a new rails app - installed Capistrano through the gemfile - and run the command again and get the same output.

Comment: p.s. "--trace" output now added to question.

Comment: `/Capfile:4` suggests that you may be running this command in the wrong directory.

Comment: Thanks engineersmnky - see "Update #2" in  question (couldn't figure out how to code format a response).

Comment: What does `cat /Capfile` return?

Comment: ```cat /Capfile``` added as Update #3

Comment: DOH!

Somehow, a Capfile had appeared in the Ubuntu root directory (/) and this was being read.

Removing this Capfile solves the problem.

Many thanks for the pointers, it's much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

A `Capfile` was in the Ubuntu root directory (/) which was causing the problem.